# Trigger an email when a name is selected from a drop down box.. Google forms / sheets

Tags: forms, google-sheets, google-forms

Trigger an email if field reads selected text..

In the response sheet - I have a column called  "Assigned To".  I have a drop down list with 3 names.  Can I trigger an email to be sent to their email address if a persons name is selected?

Here is my code so far:

```
unction myNotification(e) {
if( e.values[9] == "Barry" ) {
  var email = "Barrysemail@email.com";
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Test", "Yes is Barry");
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an installable onEdit trigger, try:

```
function sendNotification(e) {
if (e.value == 'Barry' && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    var email = 'abc@gmail.com';
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, 'test subject', 'This is Barry')
    }
}
```

and see if that works ?